# Polling API until task status is set to 'COMPLETELY_SIGNED' using React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, polling

I have a `fetch` function and `update` function to perform the task operations.
When I call the `update` function, the `taskId` is changed so I need to check if the task status is 'COMPLETELY_SIGNED" to load the next component.

```
async process({action, request}, dispatch, done) {
const {form} = action.payload

try {
  const params = {
    taskId: form.taskId,
    password: form.password
  }
  dispatch(resetTaskFormErrors())
  const response = await request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'task/update',
    params: params,
    data: form.taskRequest
  })
  dispatch(updateTaskSuccess(response.data))
  dispatch(fetchTask(response.data.id)) }
```

So I call the fetch function using the new taskID to check if the task status is "COMPLETELY_SIGNED". Unfortunately the task status won't change quickly, so I need to poll the fetch API to check until the status becomes 'COMPLETELY_SIGNED'.

When the task is updated, the response will have an `editor` object. This is used to check if the task is updated in `componentWillRecieveProps`

So I decided to handle the props change in `componentWillRecieveProps`

```
UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (!isEqual(nextProps.buyerOTPForm, this.state.task)) {
      if (nextProps.buyerOTPForm.otpData.editor &&
        nextProps.buyerOTPForm.status !== 'COMPLETELY_SIGNED') {
        this.props.fetchTask(nextProps.buyerOTPForm.otpData.id)
      }
      else if (nextProps.buyerOTPForm.otpData.editor &&
        nextProps.buyerOTPForm.status === 'COMPLETELY_SIGNED') {
        this.setState({
          isApproved: true
        })
      }
      this.setState({
        task: nextProps.buyerOTPForm.otpData,
        errors: nextProps.buyerOTPForm._errors,
        ...nextProps.signingSuccess ? {
          isSigning: false
        } : {},
        ...nextProps.rejectingSuccess ? {
          isRejecting: false
        } : {}
      }, () => {
        this.propertyPriceValidation()
      })
    }   }
```

I am getting infinite loop over here. How can I possibly resolve my issue?

Comment: making changes in 'change checkers' should be condition guarded to avoid loops -  there is a notice about this in docs

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are not comparing current props with previous props and directly doing setState. You need to check current props with previous props and if they are not equal then do setState. The below code should work

```
 UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if(nextProps.buyerOTPForm.otpData !== this.props.buyerOTPForm.otpData){
  if (nextProps.buyerOTPForm.otpData.editor &&
    nextProps.buyerOTPForm.status !== 'COMPLETELY_SIGNED') {
    this.props.fetchTask(nextProps.buyerOTPForm.otpData.id)
  }
  else if (nextProps.buyerOTPForm.otpData.editor &&
    nextProps.buyerOTPForm.status === 'COMPLETELY_SIGNED') {
    this.setState({
      isApproved: true
    })
  }
  this.setState({
    task: nextProps.buyerOTPForm.otpData,
    errors: nextProps.buyerOTPForm._errors,
    ...nextProps.signingSuccess ? {
      isSigning: false
    } : {},
    ...nextProps.rejectingSuccess ? {
      isRejecting: false
    } : {}
  }, () => {
    this.propertyPriceValidation()
  })
}
}
```

The method it self says unsafe so whenever your component receives new props this method gets called and also this method gets called twice for no reason and that’s why this is unsafe. You need to check current props with previous props always when you want to do setState in this method to avoid infinite loop.

Comment: I was keeping the current props in state.

Comment: I don’t see assigning props to task state in componentWillReceiveProps method and even if you do the state won’t be updated immediately. Have you tried what I have shared?

Comment: Yes I did. but the issue exists

Comment: Ok I directly added this if(nextProps.buyerOTPForm.otpData !== this.props.buyerOTPForm.otpData){ can you try with updated answer now